# Permutations and symmetric groups

Tags: permutations, symmetric-groups

Suppose that a permutation $f$ is the product of disjoint cycles $f_1,f_2,\dots, f_m$. Show that $o(f)$ is the least common multiple of $o(f_1), o(f_2),\dots, o(f_m)$.

Really lost with the question..

Say if there are 3 disjoint cycles, then $f=f_1*f_2*f_3$ say $f=(a,b)(c,d)(e,f)$ would that mean that $o(f)=\text{lcm}(o(f_1),o(f_2),o(f_3))$? How do you go about proving that?

I also have a second part that wants to know the order of a product of $k$-cycles;

$(1,6,4,9)(2,7,11)(3,5,8)(10,12)$? I got 12 because $\text{lcm}(4,3,3,2)$ is that true?

Comment: Whey you ask "How do you go about proving that?" do you want to know how to prove that $2$ is the least common multiple of $2$, $2$, and $2$? Or do you want to know how to find the values of $o(f)$, $o(f_1)$, etc.? (Your notation is confusing, you're using $f$ to mean two different things.) And **no**, it does **not** mean that $o(f)=o(f_1)*o(f_2)*o(f_3)$. The order of $f$ is the least common multiple, **not** the product, of the orders of the factors. In your example, $o(f)=\mathrm{lcm}(2,2,2)=2$ while $\mathrm{lcm}(2*2*2)=\mathrm{lcm}(8)=8\ne o(f)$.

Comment: To answer your last question, take $f=(1,6,4,9)(2,7,11)(3,5,8)(10,12)$ and compute $f^2,f^3,f^4,\dots$ until one of them turns out to be the identity permutation. If $o(f)=12$ is true, you should get the identity when you raise $f$ to the $12$th power, but not before that. What did you get when you tried that?

Comment: Thank you bof, i realized that after writing it down that was the wrong notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disjoint cycles commute, so, if $f_1,\dots f_m$ are disjoint, then $$(f_1f_2\dots f_m)^k=f_1^kf_2^k\dots f_m^k.$$ Since the cycles are disjoint, this product is $1$ if and only if all $f_i^k$ are $1$, so $k$ has to be a multiple of all of $o(f_1),\dots o(f_m)$. Then, the rank would be the smallest of those natural numbers, so it has to be their least common multiple.

In your first example, the rank is $2$, and the least common multiple of $2,2$ and $2$ is $2$. In your second example, $12$ is indeed the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful to me understanding the problem!

Comment: What do you mean by rank though? We haven't used that word in my text.

Comment: I mean that number $o(f)$.